# No angular moduel is being created when using command ng new

Tags: angular, angular17, ng

I am using the command `ng new <project-name>` to create a new angular project. When the project is created, though it runs properly, there is no angular module present in the project.

The `ng new` command is generating a project only with **StandAlone** components.

I am using angular 17

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in angular 17.

Now, the `ng new` command creates **StandAlone** components by default. This is what said by [angular website](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt0).

> Please note: Starting in Angular version 17 new projects will be standalone by default. To create a project with NgModule use the option ng new --no-standalone

Proper documentation about the standalone architecture pattern could be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components).